# How to filter out text fields in a complex query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I've got a lot of doc filters on my UI (date ranges, checkboxes, input fields), so the query is generated dynamically - that's why I decided to create a boolean query, and push everything to `must` array. This is the example of my request:

```
const {
    body: {
      hits
    }
  } = await esclient.search({
    from: filterQuery.page || 0,
    size: filterQuery.limit || 1000,
    index,
    body: query
  });
```

Checkboxes (I used additional `bool.should` inside `must` array) and date range work perfectly, but term/match filtering is not working at all:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
          {"match": { "issueNumber": "TEST-10" }}
        ]
    }  
  }
}
```

The query above gives me all the documents from the index that contains "TEST" (with their scores), if I change `match` to `term` - it returns an empty array.

As my field is of a type 'text', I've also tried `filter` query - ES still gives all the documents with 'TEST' word:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "match": {"issueNumber": "TEST-10"}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is how my hit looks like:

```
       {
        "_index" : "test_elastic",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bj213hj2gghg213",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "date" : "2019-11-26T13:27:01.586Z",
          "country" : "US",
          "issueNumber" : "TEST-10",
        }
```

Can someone give me input on how to filter the docs properly in complex query?

This is the structure of my index:

```
{
  "test_elasticsearch" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "country" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "date" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "issueNumber" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1574759226800",
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "PTDsdadasd-ERERER",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7040299"
        },
        "provided_name" : "logs"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a field called `issueNumber.keyword`?  If yes, then an exact match is done by using a `term` query on that field.

Comment: I've also tried with `term`, but it gives me an empty response. I've updated my post with the example of a hit

Comment: What do you get when running `GET test_elastic`?

Comment: I've updated the post with my index structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that your `issueNumber` field has not the right type, it should be `keyword` instead of `text` if your goal is to make exact searches on it. Same for `country`. Modify your mapping like this:

```
  "properties" : {
    "country" : {
      "type" : "keyword"
    },
    "date" : {
      "type" : "date"
    },
    "issueNumber" : {
      "type" : "keyword"
    }
  }
```

Then reindex your data and your queries will work.

Comment: thank you, it worked (with `term`)! can you explain why we need to use a `keyword` for the exact match and not a `text`?